Having problem with Apache Virtual host and wordpress working
I am having wordpress blog - https://blog.pepagora.com, hosted on Amazon aWS EC2 instance and DNS is managed in Route53.
Suddenly blog site stopped responding and couldn't figure out why?
For testing purpose i just created one under maintenance HTML file and tried calling that file from browser blog.pepegora.com/maintenance.html even this is not loading.
My Route53 is fine
My Virtual Host screenshot attached in pic link
Maintenance HTML File
Browser view
No Error in log
Screen shot link : https://prnt.sc/m5Blq8CsXV-U
What could be the issue? How do i Know my virtual host is correct as i checked DNSWATCH.INFO the A record is correctly pointed
I tried Apachectl configtest all syntax is OK
https://prnt.sc/_WbtfgB_uHZk

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question seems more for ServerFault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Noted i will post it in server fault

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Noted and i'll do it
Thanks for the info @Mark B
